# Where to catch EF4 ObjectContext exceptions on WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm having a hard time figuring out where to catch Entity Framework exceptions. I have `SaveChanges` and concurrency exceptions covered, however, I'm having a hard time finding a general rule to catch other exceptions (like timeouts because the server went down, or something).

I'm doing a Windows client application so exceptions cannot just spit out a "error" web page, they must give out options to continue the application (since you might have other windows opened in it, this is no simple app).

This was quite easy to figure out when using ADO.net directly: you'd trap exceptions on connection opening and query executing, however I'm not quite sure exactly *when* are connections opened and queries executed using EF4 (database-first in this case).

There are some simple cases (for example, when I actually run the enumerator on the `IQueryable`, by calling `ToList` or `ToArray`), but there are others which are not that easily found: for example, if I'm assigning an `IQueryable` to a WinForm control's `DataSource`, depending on the control behaviour (which I'm not always controlling), it may or may not actually execute the query (some controls execute it upon calling `DataBind` later).

I know I could do this by trial and error (or just doing huge `try/catch` blocks), but I'm trying to figure out a more general way to do this.

I've tried searching for some `onexception`-like event on the `ObjectContext`, but haven't found anything remotely near, and everything I find on the matter is about exceptions on `SaveChanges` and concurrency exceptions, which as I said, I have covered.

Any hints on where to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you familiar with the concept of `unit of work`? this typically defines the boundaries of when a `context` begins and ends. exception handling can then be placed in/around the unit of work to handle specific exceptions.

here is just one idea.

```
public void Execute(Action<DbContext> action)
{
    try
    {
       using(var context = new MyContext())
       {
           action(context);
           context.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
    catch(ConcurrencyException exception)
    {
    }
    catch(ValidationException exception)
    {
    }
    catch(SqlException exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd do if I was making the application from scratch... redesigning the whole application to make use of this pattern is not an option now (quite big app, too little resources, you know :-) ), that's why I was looking for a more "generic" way: something that would trigger on exceptions for EF (with a '`e.handled = true`-like parameter)... or some `OnDatabaseAction`-like event on the `ObjectContext` where I could catch exceptions on.

Seems there's none... I'll wait for other possible answers and if there's nothing better I hadn't thought of I'll mark yours as answer. 

Thanks

Comment: you could use this approach on the critical areas first and as you add new features. then, as time permits, you can refactor the legacy code (non-critical areas) to use the UoW. A full integration is not required to improve the infrastructure in a situation like this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am actually doing... there are however, many critical areas. It's not what I was looking for, but I'll give you the answer nonetheless, since it's a good alternative.

Thanks